# Input validation using character array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, validation, input, character

I am creating a C++ program to validate book name using a function in c++. The function must return 1 if the input is valid and 0 if the input is invalid. Book name can only contain upper case, lower case characters, color(:), comma(,) and space (there should be no consecutive spaces, commas, and colons). And the maximum characters in a character array is 60.

I tried the following way but I am not getting the desired answer.

```
const int MAX_BOOK_NAME = 60;

bool isValidBookName(char bookName[MAX_BOOK_NAME])
{
     int length = strlen(bookName);
     if (length > 59)
     {
          return false;
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < 59; i++)
     {
          if (bookName[i] < 'A' || bookName[i] > 'Z' || bookName[i] < 'a' || bookName[i] > 'z' || bookName[i] != '  ' || bookName[i] != ':' || bookName[i] != ',')
          {
               return false;
          }
     }

     return true;
}

int main()
{
     char arr[60];
     cout << "Please Enter Your Book Id : ";
     cin.getline(arr, 60);
     cout << "Your Entered Name is " << isValidBookName(arr) << endl;
}
```

Comment: If `length > 59` is true, then you're already in trouble as that would mean the buffer is overflowed and you already have undefined behavior because of that.

Comment: I also suggest you take a look as the [`std::isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) function, as your way to check for letters is encoding-specific and C++ doesn't assume any specific encoding.

Comment: And the loop `for (int i = 0; i < 59; i++)` disregard the string null terminator, and could go out into uninitialized areas of the array which lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Is there a reason you use C strings in C++?

Comment: "I tried the following way but I am not getting the desired answer. " Please provide expected input and expected output

Comment: A one-liner using C++:  `return std::all_of(bookName, bookName + length, isalpha);`

Comment: Any reason you are not using `std::string arr;` instead of `char arr[60]`. The former will handle the memory requirements for you eliminating your off-by-one error and preventing buffer overruns.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Ideally that would work, but it causes compiler errors (now incl. MSVC in since 16.4) because there are two versions of `isalpha` to choose from; the one in cctype and the one in locale. Best practice is to wrap with a short lambda. [like this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha)

Comment: @AndyG Yes, you're right.  Should wrap in a lambda, as I've shown already in some answers I have given in the past.  Lazy I guess...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: No worries, it's just fresh in my head b/c of the new VS version.

Comment: @OP Your code doesn't include the checking of consecutive spaces, colons, or commas.  Just to give you a hint, `std::adjacent_find` makes this also a one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> bookName[i] < 'A' || bookName[i] > 'Z' || bookName[i] < 'a' || bookName[i] > 'z'
> ```

These checks match every character because for example (assuming ASCII or compatible encoding) all capital letters match the condition `bookName[i] < 'a'` and all smaller case letters match `bookName[i] > 'Z'`. Since these checks are used to match an invalid character, the check is wrong.

`std::isalpha` can simplify your program greatly, as pointed out in comments.

Answer (score 1):

The logic of your character check is flawed.

The requirement in your question is that each character must be a letter, or a comma, or a colon, or ... etc. The reverse of that is not "not a letter or not a comma or not a colon or ... etc." The reverse is "not a letter ***and*** not a comma ***and*** not a colon ***and*** ... etc."